# Hide and show layout on click of dynamic image

Tags: android

I have created a dynamic layout for edittext with add and minus icons. When i click on add, layout should recreated again and in place of add image, minus should shown.Add icon is changed to minus on first click but minus is not changed to plus.When i clicked on minus, sub layout is removed but not able to change icon.

This is my dynamic layout:

```
    public void dLayout(){
        count++;
        lay_frame = new LinearLayout(this);
        lay_frame.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lay_frame.setId(count);

        for (int i =0; i<numClass; i++){
            lay_main = new LinearLayout(this);
            lay_uncle = new LinearLayout(this);
            lay_cousin = new LinearLayout(this);

            lay_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            lay_uncle.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            lay_uncle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            lay_cousin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            lay_cousin.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            txt_uncle = new TextView(this);
            txt_uncle.setText("Uncle Name");
            txt_uncle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt_uncle.setPadding(0, 20 , 0, 20);
            txt_uncle.setTextSize(14);

            txt_cousin = new TextView(this);
            txt_cousin.setText("Cousin Name");
            txt_cousin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt_cousin.setPadding(0, 20 , 0, 0);
            txt_cousin.setTextSize(14);

            img_add = new ImageView(this);
            img_add.setImageResource(R.drawable.add01);
            img_add.setPadding(8, 0, 0 ,0);

            img_minus = new ImageView(this);
            img_minus.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
            img_minus.setPadding(8, 0, 0 ,0);
            img_minus.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            img_cousinadd = new ImageView(this);
            img_cousinadd.setImageResource(R.drawable.add01);
            img_cousinadd.setPadding(8, 0, 0 ,0);

            img_cousinminus = new ImageView(this);
            img_cousinminus.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
            img_cousinminus.setPadding(8, 0, 0 ,0);

            ed_uncle = new EditText(this);
            ed_uncle.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            ed_uncle.setPadding(12, 8 ,8 ,8);
            ed_uncle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ed_uncle.setTextSize(14);
            ed_uncle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

            ed_cousin = new EditText(this);
            ed_cousin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            ed_cousin.setPadding(12, 8 ,8 ,8);
            ed_cousin.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ed_cousin.setTextSize(14);
            ed_cousin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80, 8.5f
            );
            params.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0);
            ed_cousin.setLayoutParams(params);
            txt_cousin.setLayoutParams(params);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80, 8.5f
            );
            params.setMargins(40, 0, 0, 0);
            ed_uncle.setLayoutParams(params1);

                img_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        img_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        img_minus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        dLayout();

                    }

                });


                img_minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (count > 0) {

                            final LinearLayout temp = (LinearLayout) mainLayout.findViewById(count);
                            mainLayout.removeView(temp);
                            count--;

                        }


                        img_minus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        img_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    }
                });

            lay_main.addView(txt_uncle);
            lay_uncle.addView(ed_uncle);
            lay_uncle.addView(img_add);
            lay_uncle.addView(img_minus);
            lay_main.addView(lay_uncle);
            lay_main.addView(txt_cousin);
            lay_cousin.addView(ed_cousin);
            lay_cousin.addView(img_cousinadd);
            lay_main.addView(lay_cousin);
            lay_frame.addView(lay_main);

        }

        mainLayout.addView(lay_frame);

    }
```

Comment: what is the functionality you have in dLayout(); method ?

Comment: public void dLayout(){
        count++;
        lay_frame = new LinearLayout(this);
        lay_frame.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lay_frame.setId(count);
...... see on top of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your btn add click logic to this

```
 img_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        dLayout();    

                        img_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        img_minus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
```

Because after setting visibility again your setting the minus button visibility gone in the dLayout(); which means the property is overridden by next value

Comment: it works but it  changes sub item plus image to minus.

Answer (score 0):

In onClick listener for minus button,lay_frame LinearLayout been removed from the main layout. Minus button is child of lay_frame layout, which is no more attached to view tree. If you are removing the view on click on minus button,changing the icon from minus to plus image doesn't make any sense.

Comment: i want  to change plus image of main lauout not for sub layout. On click of main item's plus sub layout is removed not main.